Packing/Unpacking a Vec<u8> into a Vec<u16> using only 15 bits of each u16
I need to convert a Vec<u8> as a Vec<u16>. However, the first bit of every u16 is lost due to my esoteric embedded storage medium, and I cannot control it.
Because of this, I can't simply do:
fn encode(orig: &Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u16> {
    let mut ret: Vec<u16> = Vec::with_capacity(orig.len() / 2 + (orig.len() % 2 != 0));
    let current: u16 = 0
    for n in orig {
        if current {
            current += n;
            ret.push(current);
            current = 0
        } else {
            current = n << 8;
        }
    }
    if current { ret.push(current) }
    ret
}

As the first bit in every u16 will be overwritten later.
Now, I could just store every u8 into the u16 without any encoding, however I will end up missing out on storing an additional 7 bits of data for every 8 bits stored. The platform I'm working on does not have much storage, (nor CPU or Memory) so I'd like to use what I do have most efficiently.

Can you explain where exactly you're stuck while implementing this? Cause on the face of it this seems like a relatively trivial task that just needs doing, and [so] isn't really the place for such questions.

Short of iterating one bit at a time (inefficient) I'm unsure how to tackle this

The logic required to but a bit at a specific position is no different for (part of) a byte so if you can implement the bitwise version, the (partial) byte wise, while more complex, isn't all that different.

This feels like a task for a popular automated assistant. It provides code like this that looks correct to me.

I've figured it out.
use crate::util::math::div_up;

/*
File to encode an arbitrary `Vec<u8>` as a Vec<u16> using only 15 bits of each u16

First u16 is the header. From most significant to least:
Bits    Description
1       Can't use
6       Reserved
1       Compression flag
8       Version Number, should always be 0

Second+3rd u16:
1       Can't use
15      u8 array size
 */
const VERSION: u16 = 0;
const MAX_LENGTH: usize = 2*1024*1024*15/8;

pub fn bit_15_enc(orig: &Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u16> {
    let mut header = VERSION;

    let data: &Vec<u8>;
    let lzdata;

    if orig.len() > MAX_LENGTH {
        if orig.len() >= (1<<30-1) { panic!("Input is to large to track length") }
        header |= 0b0000_0001_0000_0000;
        lzdata = lz4_flex::compress_prepend_size(orig);
        data=&lzdata;
        if data.len() > MAX_LENGTH {
            panic!("Input could not be compressed enough to fit")
        }

    } else { data = orig }

    let mut ret: Vec<u16> = Vec::with_capacity(div_up(data.len()*8, 15)+3);
    ret.push(header);

    ret.push((data.len() >> 15) as u16);
    ret.push((data.len() & 0x7fff) as u16);

    let mut accumulator: u32 = 0;
    let mut bit_count: u32 = 0;

    for &byte in data {
        accumulator = accumulator << 8;
        bit_count+=8;
        accumulator |= byte as u32;

        if bit_count >= 15 {
            bit_count-=15;
            let value = (accumulator >> (bit_count)) as u16;
            ret.push(value);
            accumulator &= (1 << bit_count) - 1; // Blank out used bits
        }
    }

    if bit_count > 0 {
        accumulator = accumulator << 15 - bit_count;
        ret.push(accumulator as u16)
    }

    ret
}

pub fn bit_15_dec(enc: &Vec<u16>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let version = enc[0] & 0xff;
    let compress_flag = enc[0] & 0b0000_0001_0000_0000;
    let total_bytes: u32 = ((enc[1] as u32 & 0x7fff) << 15) | (enc[2] as u32 & 0x7fff);
    let mut bytes_remaining = total_bytes;

    if version != VERSION {
        panic!("Version Mismatch")
    }

    let mut ret: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(bytes_remaining as usize);

    let mut accumulator: u32 = 0;
    let mut bit_count: u32 = 0;

    for &val in &enc[3..] {
        accumulator = (accumulator<<15) | (val as u32 & 0x7FFF);
        bit_count += 15;

        while bit_count >= 8 && bytes_remaining > 0 {
            bit_count -= 8;
            bytes_remaining -= 1;
            ret.push((accumulator >> bit_count) as u8);
            accumulator &= (1 << bit_count) - 1;
        }
    }

    if compress_flag > 0 {
        ret = lz4_flex::decompress_size_prepended(&ret).unwrap()
    }

    ret
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use rand::RngCore;
    use super::*;

    fn gen_random_data(len: Option<usize>) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let length = len.unwrap_or(64);
        let mut ret: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(length);

        unsafe {
            ret.set_len(length);
        }

        rng.fill_bytes(&mut ret);

        ret
    }

    #[test]
    fn bit_15_enc_dec_test () {
        let orig: Vec<u8> = gen_random_data(None);
        println!("[{}]", orig.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:#02x}", num).as_str() + ", "));
        let encoded: Vec<u16> = bit_15_enc(&orig);

        println!("enc:[{}]", encoded[3..].iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:015b}", num).as_str()));


        for &duo_byte in &encoded {
            assert_eq!(duo_byte & 0b1000_0000_0000_0000, 0,
                "Top bit of each u16 should never be set"
            )
        }

        let decoded: Vec<u8> = bit_15_dec(&encoded);

        assert_eq!(orig.len(), decoded.len(), "Original length does not match decoded length: {}:{}", orig.len(), decoded.len());

        println!("ori:[{}]", orig.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:08b}", num).as_str()));
        println!("dec:[{}]", decoded.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:08b}", num).as_str()));

        for i in 0..orig.len() {
            assert_eq!(
                orig[i], decoded[i],
                "Original does not match decoded at index[{}]: {:#08b}:{:#08b}",
                i, orig[i], decoded[i],
            )
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn bit_15_lz4_enc_dec_test() {
        let mut orig: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(MAX_LENGTH*4);
        orig.resize(orig.capacity(), 0);
        println!("[{}]", orig.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:#02x}", num).as_str() + ", "));
        let encoded: Vec<u16> = bit_15_enc(&orig);

        println!("enc:[{}]", encoded[3..].iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:015b}", num).as_str()));


        for &duo_byte in &encoded {
            assert_eq!(duo_byte & 0b1000_0000_0000_0000, 0,
                       "Top bit of each u16 should never be set"
            )
        }

        let decoded: Vec<u8> = bit_15_dec(&encoded);

        assert_eq!(orig.len(), decoded.len(), "Original length does not match decoded length: {}:{}", orig.len(), decoded.len());

        println!("ori:[{}]", orig.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:08b}", num).as_str()));
        println!("dec:[{}]", decoded.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + format!("{:08b}", num).as_str()));

        for i in 0..orig.len() {
            assert_eq!(
                orig[i], decoded[i],
                "Original does not match decoded at index[{}]: {:#08b}:{:#08b}",
                i, orig[i], decoded[i],
            )
        }
    }
}

